# Numpy reduce array to a given shape

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, reduction

I am trying to write a function that reduces a numpy ndarray to a given shape, which effectively "unbroadcasts" the array. For example, using add as the universal function, i want the following results:

- A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], reduced_shape = (1,) -> [1+2+3+4+5] = [15] (sum over axis=0)
- A = [[1,2], [1,2]], reduced_shape = (2,) -> [1+1, 2+2] = [2, 4] (sum over axis=0)
- A = [[1,2], [1,2]], reduced_shape = (1,) -> [1+2+1+2] = [6] (sum over axis=(0,1))
- A = [[[1,2], [1,2]], [[1,2], [1,2]]], reduced_shape = (2,2) -> [[1+1, 2+2], [1+1, 2+2]] = [[2,4], [2,4]] (sum over axis=0)

This is the solution i came up with:

```py
def unbroadcast(A, reduced_shape):
    fill = reduced_shape[-1] if reduced_shape else None
    reduced_axes = tuple(i for i, (a,b) in enumerate(itertools.zip_longest(A, shape, fillvalue=fill)) if a!=b)
    return np.add.reduce(A, axis=reduced_axes).reshape(shape)
```

But it feels unnecessarily complex, is there way to implement this that relies on Numpy's public API?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how this is an 'un-broadcasting'.

The straight forward way of doing your calculations is to use the `axis` parameter of `sum`:

```
In [124]: np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).sum()
Out[124]: 15
In [125]: np.array([[1,2],[1,2]]).sum(axis=0)
Out[125]: array([2, 4])
In [126]: np.array([[1,2],[1,2]]).sum(axis=(0,1))
Out[126]: 6
In [128]: np.array([[[1,2], [1,2]], [[1,2], [1,2]]]).sum(axis=0)
Out[128]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [2, 4]])
```

I don't use `reduce` as much, but looks like axis does the same:

```
In [130]: np.add.reduce(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
Out[130]: 15
In [132]: np.add.reduce(np.array([[[1,2], [1,2]], [[1,2], [1,2]]]),axis=0)
Out[132]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [2, 4]])
```

But I haven't worked out the logic of going from your `reduced_shape` to the necessary `axis` values.  With shapes like (2,) and (2,2,2), there's potential ambiguity when you say reduce the shape to (2,2).  It might be clearer if you worked with samples arrays like `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)`

Answer (score -1):

You can come up with a much more generic solution if you iterate from the right most dims. This is what numpy do when they broadcast: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules.

just add `itertools.zip_longest(reversed(list(A)), reversed(list(shape)))`